Why did my Firebase Service Account stop working?
Today I began upgrading my NestJS backend from 9 to 10. The firebase upgrade was not a major upgrade.
Firebase upgrade:

"firebase-admin": "^12.0.0" to "firebase-admin": "^12.1.1"

Initialization
firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(
    join(__dirname, "..", "..", "firebase-adminsdk.json"),
  ),
});

The path is valid and can be seen in the output:

The file is also where it is supposed to be in the dist directory:

For whatever reason I am now getting the following error:
FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: .".
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:85:19
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at NotificationsService.create (/usr/src/app/src/notifications/notifications.service.ts:93:11) {
errorInfo: {
 code: 'app/invalid-credential',
 message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: .".'
},
codePrefix: 'app'
}

Another weird thing is I have reverted back to original branch before the upgrade and now Firebase doesn't work there either.
I went into the Firebase console and generated an new private key and updated the json file and I still get the same annoying error. Does anyone have any ideas?
